# Regarding blank rows in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 separate DataFrames

1 of it contains different columns and data but also contain some blank rows

second of it contains a single column associated with the data of the first row

but because of the blank rows when I concatenate both columns the data gets wrongfully matched among both the columns.

Please help on how can I avoid this problem?

my first dataframe is:

CustomerId    age    sex

```
  0001      23     M

  0002      19     F

    

  0004      24     M
```

Okay so I have the 0003 customerId missing
The 2nd DataFrame is

Enrolled

```
yes

No

no

yes
```

So the no basically belongs to the 0004 CustomerId but when concatenating the DataFrames become

CustomerId    age    sex    Enrolled

```
 0001      23      M        yes

 0002      19      F         No

                             No

 0004      24      M        yes
```

How can I avoid this thing and concatenate both the DataFrames correctly

Comment: Hi There, welcome to SO, please see [ask] and [mcve]. Take a step back and think would my co-worker who knows nothing about this problem understand this piece of text? if not, re-frame it so anyone can understand it.

Comment: Actually I am not allowed to share the data due to my company policy, But will try to create a sample excel sheet to explain the problem I am facing.

Comment: If you can't share the actual data it's fine, but your problem can surely be reproduced in 5-6 rows of data with a sample output. I'll change my downvote once you edit your post.

Comment: Please check and please tell me is there something else that I should include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `df.reset_index(drop=True)` on the first dataframe and then concatenate the 2 dataframes. Would work then.

Comment: No not working, The result remains same even on applying this

Comment: I hope you are doing saving the df into another object, or using inplace .. ```df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)```. Do this on both dataframes.

Comment: yeah, I missed  the inplace = True previously, Thanks for your help.